# MySQL sum one column based on another

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have a fairly standard query that returns this table:

```
x  12  
y  59  
x  76  
x  35  
y  82
```

I want to sum all 'x' values and all 'y' values separately.
The result should be this:

```
x  123  
y  141
```

I don't want to do this programmaticaly, if it can be done in MySQL. How do I go about doing this?
Here's my sql query for reference:

```
SELECT
    tb1.val1,
    tb2.val2
FROM
    tb1 INNER JOIN tb2
ON
    tb1.id = tb2.id
WHERE
    (bunch of conditions unrelated to val1 and val2)
;
```

Comment: How many tables do you have and can you specify the conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `Group by` and `SUM` aggregate

```
select tb1.val1, sum(tb2.val2)
From tb1 INNER JOIN tb2
.....
Group by tb1.val1
```